# Ask phone number validation only once by session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I integrated phone number verification in my app with this tutorial
[here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/06/sms-phone-verification-in-rails-4-using-ajax-and-twilio.html), the problem is when the visitor go on a profil from my results page and back to the results page the modal of the phone number verification reappears
I would know how to ask a phone number only once

My phone verification view

```
<div class="modal show" id="myModalpin" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Vérification téléphone</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="send-pin">
          <h4>Nous allons vous envoyer un code par sms afin de vérifier votre numéro <br> Est-ce le bon numéro ?</h4>
          <%= form_for PhoneNumber.new, remote: true do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-danger", id: 'send-pin-link' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div id="verify-pin">
          <h3>Entrer votre code de comfirmation</h3>
          <%= form_tag phone_numbers_verify_path, remote: true do |f| %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'hidden_phone_number', '' %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :pin %>
          </div>
          <%= submit_tag "Verifier", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div id="status-box" class="alert alert-success">
          <p id="status-message">Status: Haven’t done anything yet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
            <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModalpin').modal('show');

    });
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and a bit dirty solution would be to add condition to the execution of your javascript.

Let say that your phone object is in `@phone` variable created in your controller.

then you can transform your code with

```
<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        <% if @phone.nil? %>
        $('#myModalpin').modal('show');
        <% end %>
    });
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

A bit cleaner would be to put it in a dedicated view file with the extension .js.erb